# Chrome and safari don't render div properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Code does work properly in ie9 & firefox but not in chrome and safari.

Jsfiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/4nsJE/

Problem is if you apply border to sliced class,

```
border: 5px solid black;
```

and give value of x=6 & y =6 in Jscript

```
$('.sliced').sliced({ x:6, y:6, speed: 1000 });
```

You can see white spaces at bottom. It happens in chrome and safari only.why?

Comment: It looks great in my Chrome.

Comment: I tried it in Firefox and Chrome and see no difference. May be you can include a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Yes same here... even tried changing the background-color of the body but no white spaces visible.

Comment: Are you using  Chrome brwser or Google Chrome browser , for your information both are different so which one you are referring to For me its working in google chrome .

Comment: Here is my firefox screen shot:-   [link](http://imageshack.us/a/img837/253/ugmm.jpg)    Chrome:-[link](http://imageshack.us/a/img607/5496/ox1t.jpg)  @daapii

Answer (score 1):

Even with the border added to the sliced class, no white spaces/borders for me.

take a look: [Imageshack](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/9379/6d7j.png)
[image: Image?]

Comment: Then i guess its me only. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about the left hand side & top gap, then it was due to `body {margin:20px}`.
Remove it , it will be fine

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i didn't mean that.